# moving elements in a list of Python

Tags: python

I have a list of integers; it contains the integer 27, but we don't know its index.

We have to find the index and then swap it with the item following it. If the index of 27 is the last element (list[-1]) than we swap 27 with the first element.

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 27] # original
my_list = [27, 2, 3, 4, 1] # result
```

I know how to swap 27 when it is not the last element, but I don't know how to swap 27 with the first element like in the example I showed.

Comment: Could you break up this run-on sentence? It would probably make your question clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once the number you are looking for always exists in the list just index and swap using modulo:

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 27]
def swap(l,n):
    ln = len(l)
    ind = my_list.index(n)
    l[ind], l[(ind + 1)% ln] = l[(ind + 1) % ln], l[ind]
```

Using `% ln` just mean we wrap around so when `ind = 5` as per your example `(4 + 1) % 5`  will be 0

Output:

```
In [45]: my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 27]

In [46]: swap(my_list, 27)

In [47]: my_list
Out[47]: [27, 2, 3, 4, 1]

In [48]: swap(my_list, 4)

In [49]: my_list
Out[49]: [27, 2, 3, 1, 4]
```

You might want to handle the case where n does not exist:

```
def swap(l,n):
    ln = len(l)
    try:
        ind = my_list.index(n)
        l[ind], l[(ind + 1)% ln] = l[(ind + 1) % ln], l[ind]
    except IndexError:
        pass
```

What you do in the except is up to you.

Comment: I think the question is to swap elements of the list. Is there a reason for introducing the argument `n` in the function?

Comment: @ssundarraj, the OP said they did not know where the element was so n is going to be whatever element they want to shift

Comment: sorry I don't know about the modulo, so can you tell me what is In [45]

Comment: @ssundarraj,  the number used in the OP's example is 27, that does not that mean 27 will be the only number ever used  and even if it were adding a more general function probably makes more sense than writing one that can only be used with the number 27

Comment: @SyedNaqi, not sure I understand what you mean by  *what is In [45]*

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Yep. You're function is well written. An oversight on my part.

Comment: I got the 27 to swap to with the first element but how can I put it together with the code when 27 is not the last element.

Comment: @SyedNaqi, that is the point of using modulo it works when n is anywhere in your list, the code will work as is.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I just wanted to know if you can tell me or give me a source where I learn more about using modulo.

Comment: @SyedNaqi, no worries,  wiki give a thorough explanation https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation

Comment: can you please explain the use of modulo in terms of this code